# Adding icon next to fieldset legend title and displaying tooltip

Tags: html, css, tooltip, fieldset

I'd like to add an icon to the right of the fieldset title.  Something like this:

```
--Title[icon]-------
|                  |
| Content          |
|                  |
--------------------
```

When you hover over the icon a tooltip is supposed to be displayed.  This is where I am having issues.  For some reason the icon is being pushed below the title (see screen shot).

[image]

Not only that, but because of my CSS, the fieldset border is around my tooltip div.  I want the fieldset border to remain the same and have the tooltip hover over the border.

I've tried playing around with the divs and CSS to get the desired effect, but nothing seems to work for me.

In summary, I'd like to have the icon appear to the right of the fieldset title and not have the fieldset border pushed around the tooltip.  Rather, I want the tooltip to hover over the fieldset border.

**UPDATE:** If JS is the only way to accomplish this, then I'd like to paste the div content elsewhere on the page and relatively position the div to the right of the icon.  In other words, no matter where the icon sits on the page, I want the div to always display to the right of it.

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Akyym/3/

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset class="GridFacet" >

<legend>Title

    <div class="tooltipContainer">  
    <a class="tooltipIcon" href="">
        <img src="/Content/themes/images/info-small-black-13px.png"/>
    </a>

        <div class="tooltip">
            <strong>A</strong> - CONTENT<br/>
            <strong>B</strong>  - CONTENT<br/>
            <strong>C</strong>  - CONTENT<br/>
            <strong>D</strong>  - CONTENT<br/>
            <strong>E</strong>  - CONTENT<br/>
        </div>
    </div>   

</legend>

        <p class="chkRow">
            <input id="H10" type="checkbox" class="chkFacet" value="h10" />
            <label for="H10" class="lblFacet">
                A</label>
        </p>
        <p class="chkRow">
            <input id="T3" type="checkbox" class="chkFacet" value="t3" />
            <label for="T3" class="lblFacet">
                B</label>
        </p>
          <p class="chkRow">
            <input id="U1" type="checkbox" class="chkFacet" value="u1" />
            <label for="U1" class="lblFacet">
                C</label>
        </p>
          <p class="chkRow">
            <input id="U2" type="checkbox" class="chkFacet" value="u2" />
            <label for="U2" class="lblFacet">
                D</label>
        </p>
          <p class="chkRow">
            <input id="U3" type="checkbox" class="chkFacet" value="u3" />
            <label for="U3" class="lblFacet">
                E</label>
        </p>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS:**

```
.GridFacet {
    width: 50px;
}

.tooltipContainer {
    width: 325px;
    position: relative;
}

.tooltipIcon {
    text-decoration: none;
}

    a.tooltipIcon:hover + div {
        display:block;
        float: right;
    }

.tooltip {
    margin: -43px 0 5px 50px;
    *margin: -12px 0 5px 15px; /* For IE7 and below */
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #e9ebec;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #739e40;
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.tooltip:after, .tooltip:before {
    border: solid transparent;
    content:' ';
    height: 0;
    right: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}

.tooltip:after {
    border-width: 11px;
    border-right-color: #e9ebec;
    top: 13px;
}

.tooltip:before {
    border-width: 14px;
    border-right-color: #739e40;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Are you objected to using JS to display the tooltip? The main problem is the `tooltipcontainer` div within the `legend` which technically only accepts 'phrasing content' and not layout content as you have: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FContent_categories#Phrasing_content . If you are ok with JS you can remove that block and move the tooltip somewhere else and display it using JS and absolute positioning instead and it should work no problem. Otherwise you'll have to use one of the supported elements listed above.

Comment: @DigTheDoug No, I'm not.  If you have a JS solution then that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Actually after taking another look you should still be able to do it the way you have but just change the div to something supported like a span, I'll post a fiddle in a moment

Comment: @DigTheDoug I actually was just about to try using a span.  Let me know if you get it to work.  However, using a `<span>` in place of a `<div>` sounds kind of hacky.

Comment: It may not technically validate because of the other div within it; that would be the only 'hacky' part I would consider, but that can be changed too if it bothers you.

Comment: @DigTheDoug Which would be more "correct" or "valid"?  A `div` inside of a `span` or another `span` inside of the `span`?

Comment: A `span` within a `span` is totally acceptable. Read up on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span. The main difference being that you usually don't want to have a block-level element (`div`) WITHIN an inline (`span`) element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the main problem is the `tooltipcontainer` `div` within the `legend` technically only accepts "phrasing content" which does not include a `div`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)

But if you change your `tooltipcontainer` `div` to a `span` element it should work fine:

```
<legend>Title <span class="tooltipContainer">  
    <a class="tooltipIcon" href="">
        <img src="/Content/themes/images/info-small-black-13px.png"/>
    </a>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <strong>A</strong> - CONTENT<br/>
            <strong>B</strong>  - CONTENT<br/>
            <strong>C</strong>  - CONTENT<br/>
            <strong>D</strong>  - CONTENT<br/>
            <strong>E</strong>  - CONTENT<br/>
        </div>
    </span> 
</legend>
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/y54Jm/).

Comment: This fixes my problem.  However, I worry about validity issues with it.  Do you think JS would be a more "acceptable" approach?

Comment: FYI- This approach also only works in Chrome.  I tested in IE and in FF and I get a flickering when hovering over the icon.

Comment: Personally I like the customizability and ease of a nice JS library, but I also understand some people's negative outlook especially if you are introducing it specifically and only for something like this. However since 99% of any of my projects already use jQuery and usually some other styling library like Bootstrap.js, adding something like a tooltip is really trivial and I think ends up looking a lot nicer.

Comment: @Kevin re:other browsers. That is a problem then for sure. I'll take a look.

Comment: @Keven The flickering in the other browsers issue is happening because the tooltip is placed at the same position as the mouse cursor so when you hover over the img the tooltip appears and when you move your mouse the pointer is no longer technically over the image, but over the tooltip. To solve you just need to increase the margin or left values to make sure the tooltip is to the right of the mouse pointer when it appears.

Comment: Sorry, not sure without looking into it. Get rid of your margin declarations to see where each lies natively and use the browsers' style inspectors to check why they are different in each case.

Comment: I decided to use `top` and `left` instead of the margin to position it and that fixed the issue for all three browsers.